# Error when mousemove arrow on image in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am a [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/tXjJY/)

```
function mouseTagObject() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
    x.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){document.getElementById('arrow').style.display = 'none';}, false);
    x.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){document.getElementById('arrow').style.display = 'block';}, false);
}
function mousemoveDiv(e) {
    document.getElementById('arrow').style.top = e.pageY - 10 + "px";
    document.getElementById('arrow').style.left = e.pageX - 15 + "px";
    mouseTagObject();
}
document.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveDiv, false);
```

And html

When I mousemove on `image tag` (slowly), `<div> tag` not hide, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

I'll admit, it gave me the slip for a minute. But the slow vs. fast thing is what did it. Imagine, why would it not work when moving slowly? Well, look at your mouse. If you move very quickly, the button gets out from under the mouse. But if you move slowly, the button stays under the mouse the whole time, meaning that it never actually enters the image. Get rid of that button or put it next to the cursor, not under it.

Also, why are you adding the event listeners from within the mousemove handler? You're going to re-add those listeners every time the mouse moves.